# PHP encoding Windows-1257 to UTF-8 error

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, converters

I encountered a problem with converting the Windows-1257 file to UTF-8. The original file has 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1257"?>`
 on top and I try to convert it using this code:

```
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
iconv_set_encoding("output_encoding", "ISO-8859-1");

$baltic_xml = file_get_contents($remote_file);
$unicode_xml = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $baltic_xml);
file_put_contents('data/rmtools/import/utf8/'.$files_single, $unicode_xml);
```

It saves the file as UTF-8, but when I open this file I still get the error:

> XML parsing error: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0x04 0x50 0x72 0x65

Is there any proper way I could convert it to readable UTF-8, or it means that there is still some symbols in the file which is NOT on UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to convert `UTF8` to `UTF8//IGNORE`, and that's why you're receiving that error. The first parameter is the in_charset. [iconv on PHP.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) Please change

```
$unicode_xml = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $baltic_xml);
```

to

```
$unicode_xml = iconv("CP1257", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $baltic_xml);
```

However I'd personally recommend you to use `mb_*` as iconv relies heavily on your OS's implementation of iconv and can show differences in between OS, mb_* on the other hand is pure php extension and is consistent. Making your code use mb_* changes whole to

```
ini_set('mbstring.substitute_character','none'); //to remove the unknown characters, in place of //IGNORE in iconv
$baltic_xml = file_get_contents($remote_file);
$unicode_xml = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $baltic_xml);
$unicode_xml = utf8_encode($unicode_xml); //to correct utf-8 bytes
$unicode_xml = preg_replace('/[^\PC\s]/u', '', $unicode_xml); //to remove control chars in case it has
file_put_contents('data/rmtools/import/utf8/' . $files_single, $unicode_xml);
```

> According to [mb supported encodings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php) CP-1257 is **not** one of them, you may use ISO-8859-13 instead, however please note that there are some inconsistencies between them in some graphical characters (language characters however seem to be consistent according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1257) )

Comment: Thank you, yet, I still get an error, this time it's: XML parsing error: encoder error

It looks like it can't read some UTF-8 symbols. Error looks like: https://d.pr/free/i/gcjyJX that symbol is Lithuanian character, which should be available on UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show you another method of doing it. I hope this will help you.

Comment: As I understand the mb_convert_encoding function doesn't support the CP1257? http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php I get an unknown encoding error.

Comment: You might be right. How about using ISO-8859-13 instead, it should be enough to do the job

Comment: According to the specs in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1257) there aren't much difference in CP-1257 with ISO-8859-13, however my answer with iconv remains intact. Did it solve your problem?

Comment: Hm, I tried to convert from ISO-8859-13 to UTF-8, this way I don't get any error or warning on the function itself, but file is still not readable and it says that Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !

Comment: Well can you add an xml as it is (as a file) so i can check and see if i can do sthg about it.

Comment: This is the file generated and converted to UTF-8. I can't open it via browser nor by XML uploader (I try to import these products to Prestashop site and I see the same error about UTF-8 encoding as I open the XML on any browser).

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/234eb34f4415a475db6f7fb8517bfa3420180815211048/c81830

Comment: Well so far from what I have seen, there is nothing wrong with the xml other than being huge (22mb). I don't know what XML uploader uses internally, but if I were you, I'd first increase the allowed post size, then increase the max memory it uses. Your xml is valid UTF-8

Comment: Hm, even if I make this file shorter (only a few products with max 100 lines in file) I still get the XML parsing error: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0x04 0x50 0x72 0x65

Comment: Shorter file: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5bb6649771a2d8957d821c340f1c399420180815214116/9b3e7b

Comment: Can you try `$unicode_xml = utf8_encode($unicode_xml);` before `file_put_contents`

Comment: Strange... this way I lost all the UTF-8 specific symbols but error still stays the same...

Comment: Finally, I solved what the problem was. Your xml file also contains control characters in it. I've updated my answer according to it as well.

Comment: Nice, looks like it's starting to work, one problem left is that I need to change the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1257"?> line to utf-8. Should I just remove the first line of XML and add new one with UTF-8 or I can change it using some function?

Comment: Use str_replace

Comment: So yeah the main thing was to replace the preg_replace('/[^\PC\s]/u', '', $unicode_xml); chars.

Comment: P.S. I used notepad++ to check the xml file. It shows control characters with a graphical icon, that's how I noticed them.